# Algorithm to generate set(s) with exactly 1 element intersecting with other sets in a group

Tags: python, c, algorithm, set

There is a algorithm called Maekawa, to send message to a particular request set (http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs5204/fall99/Supplemental/ProblemSet8.html)

I am interested in the ALgorithm to generate Request set for value K=3 ( 3 Elements in Set), N=7 ( 7 Such sets)

Each set when intersected with other, should yield "one" common value. How this can be generated algorithmically

Comment: What ideas do you have?

Answer (score 3):

These structures are studied within design theory, a part of combinatorics. You might be able to use a brute force search, but that won't get you very far.

A collection of sets so that the intersection of any two sets has size one is dual to a [linear space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_space_%28geometry%29), where every two points determine a unique line. The easiest ways to generate linear spaces generalize coordinate geometry by using finite fields instead of real numbers for coordinates. For example, the [Fano plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) is a projective plane over the field with 2 elements. You can let the points correspond to the 7 nonzero binary vectors of length 3 where the lines correspond to the triples whose sums are (1,1,1) where each coordinate is added mod 2. There are other descriptions, such as {{i, i+1, i+3}} where i ranges from 0 through 6 and each element is reduced mod 7. Projective planes are dual to projective planes, with the same number of points and lines, so this is already the dual of a linear space, and every pair of lines intersects in one point. The Fano plane is probably what you want with those parameters.

An affine plane over the integers mod a prime p is easier to describe than a projective plane. The points are pairs of elements of the integers mod p. Lines can be described as the solutions of ax+by=c where all of the arithmetic is done mod p and a and b can't both be 0. When p=3, there are 9 points and 12 lines. Through each point, there are 4 lines, one of each slope:  0, 1, 2, and vertical. The structure you want is the dual, so the sets correspond to the points in the plane, and the elements correspond to the lines containing those points. This gives a structure with 12 elements and 9 sets of size 4.

In the game [Set](http://www.setgame.com/set), you try to identify lines in affine 4-space over the integers mod 3, though not in as many words. This is a linear space with 81 points and 40 lines through each point, so it is dual to a structure with 1080 elements and 81 subsets consisting of 40 points so that each pair of subsets intersects in one element.